# How to reset/clear React Context with a button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can't clear context even when I'm setting the state to null in the context file. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? This is my code:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const MembersContext = createContext([{}, () => {}]);

export const MembersProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [members, setMembers] = useState(null);
  const refreshMembers = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await request('api/members');
      setMembers(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR: ', error);
    }
  };

  const clearMembers = () => {
    setMembers(null);
    console.log('CLEARED MEMBERS IN CONTEXT FILE', members); // not cleared
  };

  return (
    <MembersContext.Provider
      value={{
        members,
        clearMembers,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MembersContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then in my sign out page I have a button to use the clear context function:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import { MembersContext } from '../MembersContext';

const Settings = () => {
  const { clearMembers, members } = useContext(MembersContext);
 
  const clearContext = () => {
    clearMembers();
    console.log('CLEARED MEMBERS?: ', members); // not cleared
    //logout()
  };

  return (
   <Button onPress={()=> clearContext()}>Log Out</Button>
  );
};

export default Settings;
```

My console log and screen still shows the data from the previous session.

Comment: Hi Jae. Can you upload this to a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see both scenarios :-

- `console.log('CLEARED MEMBERS?: ', members); // not cleared` - Here you're not logging the value of `members` that will get updated but the value of `members` on which `clearContext()` closed over i.e. the current state value (before update).
- `console.log('CLEARED MEMBERS IN CONTEXT FILE', members); // not cleared` - This isn't the right way to see if `members` changed. The state
  update is `async`. Doing a `console.log(...)` just after updating
  `members` won't work. And I think the reason is same as above. It won't work because the `clearMembers()` function closes over current value of `members`.

Each update to `members` also result's in a new `clearMembers()`/`clearContext()` (due to **re-render**), atleast in this case. That's why these functions can always access the latest state.

To check whether `members` actually updated, log the value either in the **function body** of `Settings` or inside `useEffect` with `members` in it's **dependency array**.